# MemSQL: client-side prepare statement by libmysql.dll

Tags: prepared-statement, server-side, client-side, singlestore, mysql-proxy

Can someone tell me if "libmysql"dll" exists with a "client-side prepared statements"?

https://docs.memsql.com/concepts/v6.5/prepared-statements/
in the documentation I see that "server-side prepared statements" are not supported by MemSQL

What if I can't switch to another library? Software source code that fills the database cannot be changed

Comment: Is there a MySQL Proxy which can do client-side prepare statements?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's an option for the mysql c/c++ client. You could try adding the mysql tag to the question since that's a question about a mysql client.

However, if there's no client-side option and you can't switch to another client driver, one thing you could try is using the experimental support by setting `enable_binary_protocol=true`. As mentioned in the docs:

> MemSQL has an experimental, prototype implementation of server-side prepared statements, which is not supported in production. It is disabled by default, and may be enabled by setting enable_binary_protocol=true

It is known to work for some use cases and not work for others. Let us know how it goes if you test it out.

Comment: Thanks. I tried, but unfortunately not all requests work